# Is C a regular language?

Tags: programming-languages, c++, c, perl

Are C or C++ [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)? If not, under which category do we place the programming languages like C/C++, perl, Python?

Comment: No, egrep is a regular language; C is not.

Comment: Most programming language are some sort of context free language. This is why they are usually represented as tree during compilation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar

Comment: @LaurentBourgault-Roy I'd think most weren't even context free as even if they have a CFG there are usually additional rules applied outside the CFG

Comment: Even regex aren't regular anymore

Answer (score 31):

The only universal definition I know of for "regular language" is one that can be parsed with a deterministic finite automaton, or expressed as a true regular expression (not the extended REs in many current implementations).  A regular expression can be written in a series of characters, with potentially infinite repetitions and alternate selections.

Since both C and C++ allow nesting of braces, brackets, and parentheses to arbitrary depths, they aren't regular languages (check out the Pumping Lemma for details).

Comment: I would add that no programming language of any use can be regular because it wouldn't even allow any kind of numeric expressions.

Comment: @Giorgio you can express a numeric expression as a regular language (an alternating sequence of operator and number beginning and ending with a number) parsing (with priorities) them needs a grammar though

Comment: @ratchet freak: How would you handle the parentheses, e.g. in `(1 + 2) * 6`?

Comment: @Giorgio I should have added "without parenthesis"

Comment: @ratchet freak: Yes, you can find a suitable definition of what a numeric expression is so that, according to your definition, numeric expressions form a regular language.

Comment: @Giorgio a stack based language (postfix notation) avoids the issue of numeric expressions and nesting of parentheses.  The expression `(1 + 2) * 6` would be written as `1 2 + 6 *` (or `6 1 2 + *`). Look at [dc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_(computer_program)) for an example of this.

Comment: @MichaelT: Even without parentheses, I doubt that the language of correct postfix expressions can be a regular language. The problem does not lie in the parentheses themselves but rather in recognizing words that have an arbitrarily complex recursive structure. For example, how do you ensure that each time you encounter an operator in a postfix expression, you have already parsed the right number of sub-expressions, recursively? Can you write a regular expression for that?

Comment: @Giorgio you don't.  But thats a runtime error, not a 'compile time' error.  The specification of what a valid program is, is very likely regular (I admit I don't know for sure).

Comment: @MichaelT: Well, the fact that you need a stack to process a postfix expression is already a sign that the language is probably non-regular. Regular means that it can be recognized by a finite automaton, i.e. by only using a finite number of different states and no stack at all. A finite automaton has a finite memory of what it has already seen. A stack gives you an arbitrarily large memory to store intermediate results: this makes a huge difference.

Comment: The *programming* language for dc may be regular.  I know 6502 assembly *is* regular, but that doesn't say anything about what it can express. The C language is context free, but you need a turing machine (or an oracle) to see what it does.

Comment: I have looked into it. You can use the pumping lemma for regular languages to show that postfix expressions do not form a regular language. If you know how to open a chat room I can explain you the proof.

Comment: @Giorgio: It is trivially true that syntactically correct postfix expressions do not form a regular language. No matter. A language can be both regular and arbitrarily expressive, including postfix expressions, as long as stack checking is deferred until runtime. Forth is an excellent example, and dc would be another.